# UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\u2019'

Tags: python, api, twitter

I get an error message when I try and send Twitter Tweets to an email. The error message is:

UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\u2019' in position 114: ordinal not in range(128)

My code is as follows:

```
# Python 3.9

import smtplib, requests
import datetime as datetime

# twitter api function (not shown) retrieves a series of tweets - these are added to a dictionary (below)


tweets = {'climate change': 'Eco1stArt - USATeam Animal rides to the rescue in nine-year-old Zac’s latest book about the climate change emergency #books -  twitter short URL  \ncaykahvekeyfi - istanbultwitter short URL\nMaura2e2_ - Killaloe Co. ClareÉirePoliticians refusing to treat the #ClimateEmergency as an emergency are committing crimes against humanity.twitter short URL\n"}

# I cant show the actual twitter short URLs in teh tweet data - 
# code to convert the dictionary into a formatted string

tweeter = ""
for k, v in tweets.items():
    tweeter += f"\n{k}\n"
    tweeter += f"{v}"

# code to build and send the email

subject = "Todays Tweets.."
email_address = "miles-s@hotmail.co.uk"

curr_date = get_date()
my_email = "email@email.com"
PW = "mypassword"
Gmail = "smtp.service.com"
with smtplib.SMTP("smtp.service.com", port=587) as connection:
    connection.starttls() # decures the email message
    connection.login(user=my_email, password = PW)
    connection.sendmail(
        from_addr=my_email,
        to_addrs=email_address,
        msg=f"Subject:{subject}\n\n{message}\n"
    )
```

Any suggestion to resolve the problem with the character '\u2019'. Thanks.

Comment: Did you try to use `SMTPUTF8` in the `mail_options` parameter of [`sendmail`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/smtplib.html#smtplib.SMTP.sendmail)?

Comment: I'll try that option also. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

sorted

I use the following code:

import re

tweeter = re.sub(r'[^\x00-\x7f]',r' ',tweeter)

and that fixed the script.

Comment: So you don't want to send the full text but only those characters in the very limited ASCII set?

Comment: No I want to send the text with the twitter URL. Seems to be working now.